# Length of stay USA B-1/B-2 visas

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

Please confirm the duration of stay for B-1 /B-2 visas for the United States, for citizens of Nigeria. I have an invitation for a conference.

Comment: The default duration is six months, but there's no guarantee you'll get that if you're admitted.

Comment: You will most probably be admitted for 6 months but unless that conference is 6 months long, you will have problems the next time you try to enter or apply for a visa.

Comment: It may also depend on whether you are being admitted as B1 or B2. Conference sounds like B1.

Answer (score 1):

The length of stay is decided by the CBP officer when you enter the United States. The **maximum** length of stay cannot exceed six months. But you might get lower length of stay depending on:

- Your remaining passport validity;
- Your answer to the question, "how long you intend to stay in United States?"
- Your resources (i.e. date of return ticket, financial means etc)

Also for visa individuals the length of stay could be extended once you're in the United States if there is chance in circumstances USCIS finds acceptable.

Comment: Technically, the regulations say that the maximum for B-1 or B-2 is one year, but I think for B2 it's only longer than 6 months in very rare circumstances.